# Running android apps on a USB device without an "Other Devices" folder in Device Manager?

Tags: java, android, windows, intellij-idea

Okay, so I am trying to run Android Apps with **Libgdx** in **Intellij** Idea on my nexus 9 and I am using Windows 10. I've downloaded the Google driver from the SDK Manager, turned on USB debugging, plugged in my device, and have set the USB computer connection as Media device (MTP).

Even so, when I go to Device Manager, I can't seem to find an "Other Devices" folder at all. My device is located under "Portable Devices" and when I right click and select update drivers and then specify where the google driver is, Windows tells me that it has identified that Media device (MTP) is the best (and only) driver available. It doesn't say anything about the ADB.

I even tried uninstalling the Google Driver and then trying to update the driver in Device Manager, but it still doesn't work. I've also tried switching the the USB computer connection to Camera (PTP) and that didn't work either. Whenever I go back into Intellij Idea and try to run the a program on a USB device, I get a message saying **"USB device not found"**.

I've been looking for an answer to this question for the last 5 days and I still haven't found it, so I really appreciate any help you can give me, thanks.

*Edit:
Hey everyone, for some reason an other devices folder just appreared randomly. I have no idea why, but it works. Thank you to everyone who answered my question or edited my question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'm on Windows 10 too. As soon as I plugged in my device in MTP mode and turned developer options on, the Android Studio immediately finds it

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I just want to ask you: did you have an other devices folder in Device Manager ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped going to the sdk instaltion folder, then **\extras\google\usb_driver** and right-click on ***inf** file and click "install"

Maybe it will be useful for someone.